# Semantic meanings of std::auto_ptr and boost::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, auto-ptr, aliases

In our large project we have a lot class with the following `typedef`'s:

```
class Foo
{
  public:
    typedef std::auto_ptr<Foo> Ptr;
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<Foo> Ref;
  ...
};
...
Foo::Ref foo(new Foo);
...
doBar(foo);
...
```

The using of them is very convenient. But I doubt if `auto_ptr` is semantically close to `Ptr` and `shared_ptr` is the same as ref? Or should `auto_ptr` be used explicitly since it has "ownership transfer" semantics?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

`std::auto_ptr` has ownership transfer semantics, but it's quite broken. If you can use `boost::shared_ptr`, then you should use `boost::unique_ptr` instead of `std::auto_ptr`, since it does what one would expect. It transfers ownership **and** makes the previous instance invalid, which `std::auto_ptr` doesn't.

Even better, if you **can** use C++11, then swap to `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: `std::auto_ptr` isn't broken.  As specified, it's overly complex, but it
works well for what it was designed for, and is certainly more useful
than `boost::shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use `std::auto_ptr`, its deprecated and I consider it dangerous, even more so when you hide it behind such a generic typedef as `Ptr`.

I don't think it makes any sense to called `shared_ptr`Ref, in this case it is more `Ptr` than `auto_ptr`.

EDIT: I consider it dangerous because you can easily misuse it, even when you fully understand its workings, you can accidentally misuse it, especially when hiding it behind a typedef. A good class should be easy to use right and **should be difficult to misuse**. Especially with the advent of `unique_ptr` I can't see any useful scenario for `auto_ptr`.

Comment: Who considers `std::auto_ptr` dangerous?

Comment: James Kanze: I do. Edited the answer.

Comment: How does a language feature(`auto_ptr` in this case) which is just difficult for most people to understand and use wisely become *dangerous*, I think `auto_ptr` is rather very useful if used wisely.You should probably state *`auto_ptr` usage is dangerous if you don't understand how it works.*

Comment: @phresnel That's true for most of the standard library:-): iterators, iostream manipulators, `streambuf` etc.  That doesn't mean *dangerous*, however.  When you need the semantics of `std::auto_ptr`, there are very few alternatives, and it works well.  I've used it in almost all applications since it has become stable, and I've yet to see it cause problems for any maintenance programmer.

Comment: Als: If it wasn't dangerous and useful, why would they deprecate it? I don't know of any single case where ´auto_ptr´ is useful. When is ´auto_ptr´ useful according to you?

Comment: Now I'm getting curious, when do you guys find `auto_ptr` useful over the standard smart-pointers, `shared_ptr` and `unique_ptr`?

Comment: @ronag: `std::auto_ptr` is deprecated because `std::unique_ptr` implements the same contract while making it more flexible without compromising the integrity: `std::unique_ptr` can be move while `std::auto_ptr` cannot. The reason for this is the absence of rvalue reference support in C++2003. When use of rvalue references is an option, `std::unique_ptr` is the better choice.

Comment: I don't think so: there is nothing wring with using`std::auto_ptr` in C++2003 code which is, realistically, still the vast majority of the production code. Also, replacing `std::auto_ptr` with some form of shared pointer would be outright wrong: the latter enforces a memory management scheme.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: In the C++03 case I would suggest `boost::scoped_ptr`, possibly with `boost::move` (if support have been added to `scoped_ptr`?, otherwise roll your own). If you don't have boost I would suggest you roll your own. I can agree that `auto_ptr` is useful when you are using C++03 and want transfer of ownership (though I believe that is a rare use-case).

Comment: @ronag: returning objects allocated from spme sort of factory is a reasonably common use case. I don't have a lot use for scoped objects allocated on the heap: I prefer to have them allocated on the stack or directly embedded init the object.

Answer (score 0):

`auto_ptr` is deprecated in C++11. You might want to stop using it and just use the `shared_ptr`. For `shared_ptr`, there is no ownership transfer on assignment, the number of references to the object is counted and the object is destroyed when the last pointer is destroyed.

Comment: _is_ deprecated. Now that we've arrived 2012, this should be apparent ;)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the order is just a nomenclature which someone used.
It probably should have been, `ref` for `auto_ptr` and `ptr` for `shared_ptr`, because:

References are immutable and hence cannot be made to refer to other object. `auto_ptr` has a similar(albeit remotely similar) semantics, transfer of ownership which means you would probably not want to assign a auto_ptr for the non-intuitive behavior it shows. The assigned object gains ownership while the object being assigned loses ownership.

On the Other hand `shared_ptr` has an reference counting mechanism which is similar(again remotely) to multiple pointers which can point to the same object. The ownership of the pointer rests with the `shared_ptr` itself and it gets deallocated as soon as there are no pointer instances referring to it.

Answer (score 0):

A lot depends on what they are being used for.  And in the case of
`Ref`, what people understand by it.  In pre-standard days, I would
often use a typedef to `Ptr` for my (invasive) reference counted
pointer; the presence of such a typedef was, in fact, an indication that
the type supported reference counting, and that it should always be 
dynamically allocated.

Both `std::auto_ptr` and `boost::shared_ptr` have very special
semantics.  I'd tend not to use typedefs for them, both because of the
special semantics, and because (unlike the case of my invasive reference
counted pointer) they are totally independent of the type pointed to.
For any given type, you can use them or not, as the program logic
requires.  (Because of its particular semantics, I find a fair number of
uses for `std::auto_ptr`.  I tend to avoid `boost::shared_ptr`, however;
it's rather dangerous.)